# Swiper (iDangero.us) Slider comes on to of Navigation bar

Tags: html, swiper.js

I have used the above code to place a navigation bar on top and then a swiper image slider next but it seems the navigation bar appears inside the slider and when scrolling down it appars after swiper.

```
<div class="w3-top">
    <!-- Navigation bar section-->
    <div class="w3-bar w3-card w3-animate-top w3-green" id="myNavbar">
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item "> <img src="img/Grawia.bmp" height="50"></a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Products</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">About Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF Navigation bar section -->
</div>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
    // Change style of navbar on scroll

    window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollEffect()
    };

    function scrollEffect() {
        var navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            navbar.className = "w3-bar" + " w3-card" + " w3-animate-top" + " w3-red";
        } else {
            navbar.className = navbar.className.replace("w3-bar w3-card w3-animate-top w3-red", "w3-bar w3-card w3-animate-top w3-red");
        }

    }

    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: 2500,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
    });
</script>
```

Swiper separately and Navigation bar separately works fine. Issue is when both are in